# How to detect Natural Language dates in strings in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nlp

I'm trying to detect dates written in natural language in a string in Swift using NSDataDetector with `.date` CheckingType but it doesn't work for all natural language dates: for instance last week, next month, last year etc. but works if the string has more specific date components.

Here is some sample code:

```
let string = "I will be free next Monday at 3 PM" // match found - worked corrected
// let string = "we had the meeting last month" // no match found does not work - returns nil

let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.date]
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

let matches = detector.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
for match in matches {
    if let date = match.date {
        print(date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .shortened))
    }
}
```

Also tried using `RelativeDateTimeFormatter()` but it's only supports Date object to String and not the other way round.

What would be the best approach to detect natural language dates in strings that include week, month, year, name of month etc.

Comment: What would "last month" be? It's a very inexact phrase that is impossible to translate to a specific date.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would expect to get a Date range for instance of the beginning of last month to the end of the month relative to the current date.

Comment: But that is not correct (unless the meeting lasted a full month :)).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You're right, but I was expecting that when date is not so specific should at least return available date component. For instance if string contains "last Sunday", the date returned starts at 12:00am since the hour and minute components weren't provided.

Comment: With your sentence 'last month' you are not defining a date, you  are defining a period. It's like to say 'Last year I was 18', it is not interpreted as a usable date.
@JoakimDanielson is right.

Comment: Hi @OluwatobiOmotayo, do you know how I can get a match from "I will be free in 2 hours/minutes"? I don't know how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @Cyril I think Apple have to expand their natural language model, I was able to get support for last week, last month by training my own model with CreateML. Google ML Kit can also detect more entities than what is available in iOS SDK.